# SQL Full-Text Search (CONTAINSTABLE) - Better String Parser?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently using a RadSearchBox (Telerik) for AutoComplete purposes to collect the search string from a user and pass it to a stored procedure that queries against a MS SQL full-text index (400k+ rows) fairly fast and returns the results in a RadGrid. The customer wants (as they always do) for the search string parser to be more advanced. I currently have it so if it detects any non-alphanumeric characters ("/","-",etc) it will search for the "exact/phrase", as full-text doesn't do well with " * exact/phrase * ".

But, before I completely re-create the wheel, I was wondering if anyone out there has something more intelligent that will insert 'AND','OR','NEAR', search for "exact/phrase" and " * exact * " OR " * phrase * " and return the results back racked and stacked based on the CONTAINSTABLE ranking. Having FORMSOF(INFLECTION,exact) would be icing on the cake.

I know this is a lot to ask, just putting a "line out" to see if anyone has anything decent they would be willing to share. I would look into using Lucene, but the web app has a Fluent Data Model that isn't easily compatible (that I know of) with Lucene.

I've done my fair share of googling, but can't seem to find anything that looks clean (would prefer not to dive into and out of numerous functions/stored procedures to accomplish) and also something that was written within the last several years.

Thanks in advance...